# Any android app capable of storing "unsent tweet" then send it out when internet connection is resumed?

Tags: twitter

As question, I have found something called `offline twitter`, but seems that it is broken in my HTC ChaCha, as I can't copy the "pin number" from twitter site back to `offline twitter`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A number of 3rd-party "social" apps have this feature.

Personally I use [TweetDeck](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.thedeck.android.app).  When Internet connection is not available, it will save my tweet, and throw a notification saying that it will be sent when connectivity is re-established.

Comment: Same for me with twicca.